# How to resolve ImportError: cannot import name 'makeMappingArray' from 'matplotlib.colors'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, word-cloud

I am just learning to code using the wordcloud and stylecloud libraries in python 3.9.0. I wrote the basic code for the stylecloud library but it gives an error that says:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'makeMappingArray' from 'matplotlib.colors'`

This is the code:

```
import wordcloud
import matplotlib
def cloud_design():
    stylecloud.gen_stylecloud(file_path=r"C:\Users\Edwin Anil\OneDrive - AL RAYAN HOLDING CO\ALL PYTHON CODES\word cloud text file.txt",icon_name="<i class='fas fa-guitar'></i>")
cloud_design()
```

The version of wordcloud that is being used is `wordcloud-1.8.1`.
The version of matplotlib that is being used is `matplotlib-3.4.1`.

this is the entire error message:

````
  File "C:\Users\Edwin Anil\OneDrive - AL RAYAN HOLDING CO\ALL PYTHON CODES\word cloud.py", line 1, in <module>
    import stylecloud
  File "C:\Users\Edwin Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\stylecloud\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .stylecloud import gen_stylecloud
  File "C:\Users\Edwin Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\stylecloud\stylecloud.py", line 6, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import makeMappingArray, to_rgb
ImportError: cannot import name 'makeMappingArray' from 'matplotlib.colors' (C:\Users\Edwin Anil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py)```

I did try various other syntax forms for import and tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib too but I don't seem to figure it out. Some help is appreciated.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you copy the html,you just need to put the class name. example "fas fa-guitar":

```
import wordcloud
import matplotlib
import stylecloud
def cloud_design():
    stylecloud.gen_stylecloud(file_path="my_random.txt",icon_name="fas fa-guitar")
cloud_design()
```

output:
[guitar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5SXB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so according to @simpleApp's solution. I tried downgrading to an older version of matplotlib and it worked.

The cmd command was `pip install matplotlib==3.2.2`

Here is the result:

[image]